# Looking for something like a private interface

Tags: c#

I have something that has been bugging me as of late. You see, I find myself writing the exact same private function over and over again throughout the various classes of my game. Essentially, it is just a method that builds the class object; it is an Initialization method. Here is a brief example:

```
public class MyClass {

public MyClass() {
    Initialize();
}

private void Initialize() {
    // do kung fu
}
}
```

As you can see, the private method is called within the constructor. I think i might have done something like this at least twenty+ times in my current project. Now I want an easy way to implement it--via visual studio/resharpers refractoring--easily.

When using visual studio, and an interface, you are required to subscribe to all the interface methods. I like this; visual studio automatically helps me do it and I like the subscription-based usage of interfaces.

The only real problem is that interfaces can't have private methods. So, I guess my question is: What is the next best thing that would help facilitate a private (and required) method, meanwhile acting like an interface? I should also mention that inheritance is out of the question because most of the classes are in no way functionally related.

Comment: Probably a dead end here.

Comment: "I should also mention that inheritance is out of the question because most of the classes are in no way functionally related". So what? Why not using only one base class?

Comment: maybe create an abstract class with an abstract method ?

Comment: Go back to the root of the problem. _" the private method is called within the constructor. I think i might have done something like this at least twenty+ times in my current project"_ - why? Why do you like that pattern so much you copy-pasta'd it all over the place? What does `Initialize()` do? Isn't there another pattern that can solve this problem in a better way?

Comment: You'll might be interested in the decorator pattern. Although I don't know anything about the structure of your code, this kind of issues may arise when the pattern is applicable. https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Decorator_pattern *a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class*

Comment: Why would you want to do something like an Initialize function into a formal interface? Do the initialisers have common features that you can extract into a common function? Otherwise, an Initialize function is basically just a constructor, and there's a lovely pre-existing pattern for constructors.

Comment: Interfaces can be internal and they can be implemented via explicit implementation.

Comment: The question doesn't give enough context for a proper answer. Might well be an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for cannot be done via a clever use of the type system.

(If inheritance were not out of the question, you could have created a `abstract` base class with an `protected abstract Initialize()` method and a `protected` constructor calling the former method.)

If you're working with Visual Studio, I suggest that you **create an IDE code snippet** along these lines:

```
class <ClassName>
{
    public <ClassName>
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // do kung fu
    }
}
```

You can then assign a short letter combination to it, e.g. `cwinit`, and whenever you type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, that snippet is inserted for you and you can override the `<ClassName>` placeholder.

You can create such a snippet e.g. with the [Snippet Designer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392).

Comment: I already knew about this. I just wanted to know if there was a way to programmatically accomplish something similar. ...and still waiting for @Jon Skeet to grace us with his infallible intellect.

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you should write object construction code inside the constructor, not in a separate method you call.

Second, your approach is broken: you can force a class to implement a method, but you can't force it to be called. Since calling methods from inside the constructor is dangerous (due to half-initialized instances), when using `virtual` methods with derived classes. I think you should avoid using that at all.

There isn't something like a private interface. Interfaces are meant to tell the outside world some of the characteristics of the type, not the inside of the class. Besides that, you can't force calling the method, so this approach is wrong.

The only (working) possibility you have to enforce this is by creating an abstract base class, with an abstract `Intitialize` method, but I doubt whether that is the way to go (I wouldn't recommend that).

Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    protected abstract void Initialize();
}
```

Comment: I will go ahead and point the finger at .Net, which does something similar. "InitializeComponent". Which is called in the constructor. Are you saying Microsoft and Jon Skeet are wrong?

Comment: Who is Jon Skeet? Never heard of... The reason they use an `InitializeComponent` method is that the other code is in another `partial` implementation of the class. It must to this in order to work. (And it is generated code, so the 'risk of error' is very low)

Comment: It is okay to do initialization calling a private method, provided you have to do a lot of repetitive things, such as building a GUI. Visual Studio, and MonoDevelop, does it (such as many others). You don't have the problem of "half-initialized" instances because a private method in C# is also not virtual.

Comment: @Krythic If you bring Jon Skeet in the discussion, than at least point to one of his posts.

Comment: Can the down-voter explain please? Don't like Jon Skeet jokes?

Comment: I've already made a comment... plus, where's the answer to the question?

Comment: @Baltasarq: I answer the question in the last sentence. That will enforce both the required method and calling that method. And doing that is not okay. It should be prevented.

Comment: Patrick, I repeat what I said in my comment. You're saying that calling a method from withing a constructor is wrong, which is not (unless it is a virtual method, in which case you're right in your answer, though it is not the case). About your answer... the OP does not want a public method [edited: okay, maybe protected is better, but the OP does not want inheritance neither].

Comment: I suggest you change the accessibility of your class' constructor from `public` to `protected` to make it clear that its supposed to be called only by an inheriting class.

Comment: @Baltasarq okay. I updated my answer to be more precise.

Comment: As for your newest update/edit I already stated that inheritance was not an option.

Comment: @stakx: Possibly, but the class is `abstract`, so it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: @Krythic: Then don't use it. It is the only working possibility.

Comment: @Krythic: You can't ping Jon from comments if he didn't participate in the quesiton btw.

Answer (score 0):

Im my opinion abstract class is a bad idea here at least for the reason that it's possible to inherit only from one other class and no more. How about:

1. Create and implement interface that is public, but not use it; It is impossible to create instance of interface type;
2. Use some sort of helper class that accepts your class instance as ref argument;

   class SettingsInit
   {
      static YourClassName SetValue(ref YourClassName instance)
      {
          ... your logic here
      }
   }